# Is there anyway to skip the uppercase or lowercase in schell script?

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

I have images starting with favorite-foodname.jpg

My script should move all images starting with fav but end differently
so the script say fav*.jpg

But the images i recieved are in uppercase ( Fav.. ), and the script wasn't running correclty

Do you have any idea or advice please?

The only solution i got is to rename them manually before running the script but i'm sure maybe there is something I missed/forget to do for skipping the sensative case.

Comment: What's preventing you from writing `Fav*.jpg` instead of `fav*.jpg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rename the file to lower case, use this :

```
for file in fav*.jpg; do
    new_file="$(echo "$file" | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')"
    mv -i "$file" "/new/path/$new_file"
done
```

Comment: If using modern bash, `new_file=${file,,}` is much more efficient than using `tr` here. (The convert-to-all-caps version is `${file^^}`)

Comment: That said, `-i` isn't ignore-case, it's "interactive", aka whether to prompt before overwriting preexisting files. `mv` only gets started **after** the shell has figured out which filenames to pass it as arguments, so an argument to mv can't possibly change whether that glob expression is case-sensitive. This is a shell configuration problem (in bash, the configuration knob to tweak is `nocaseglob`).